# Outlook and IMAP accounts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

I am using Outlook 2010 and had a POP account which i am now re-creating as an IMAP account, the problem is that i cannot get rid of the .pst file associated with the pOP account.
Is there a way to do this?
when i try to select the IMAP as the default it won't even give me the option.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the pst file and reload the outlook.

Check [this link](http://www.zensoftware.co.uk/kb/article.aspx?id=10156) as well.